# INSERT OR UPDATE if record already exists MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to write a MySQL query for insert or update some fields. I've seen about the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, but my fields are not `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`, only the combination is unique. Here is the fields list:

> ID (PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT BIGINT), user (BIGINT), creator (BIGINT), type (TINYINT), value (BIGINT), date (INT), readed (TINYINT), erased (TINYINT).

The table name is notifications (if it can be useful). I need to insert a new record or update the existent one if the user, creator, type, values are all the same of the values to insert (so like `AND`). How I can do that?

Comment: add a unique key on the combination. a key can be on multiple fields

Comment: insert or update if exists is what [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) is for

Comment: @Dagon, using the UNIQUE on the field USER for example, after that I can insert two row with the same USER value, but the others different?

Comment: er no it would not be a unique field if you had duplicates.

Comment: There's a way for use the INSERT/UPDATE with the ON DUPLICATE for the UNIQUE table cells using multiple IDs, from a SELECT, and the other fields informations static?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique index on the variable.  I'm not sure which are the variables in question, but here is an example:

```
create unique index idx_table_user_creator_type on table(user, creator, type)
```

You can also do this in the `create table` statement as well, using the syntax for a `unique` constraint.

You would then use the constraint as:

```
insert into table(user, creator, type, col1, . . .)
    values(@user, @creator, @type, . . .)
    on duplicate key update col1 = values(col1),
                            col2 = values(col2),
                            . . . ;
```